# Android App Link - Testing the flow in local environment

Tags: android, android-deep-link, android-app-links

I'm trying to check how `App Links` work on android.

Here is what I have done so far -

1. Set up a local server with MAMP, apache points to port 80.
2. Created .well-known in the `htdocs` & also put the assetlinks.json in the created dir.
3. I am able to access it using - http://192.168.0.78/.well-known/assetlinks.json

where `192.168.0.78` is my lan ip. I generated the SHA using the `keytool` command.

Here are the contents of the file `assetlinks.json`:

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.pbc.deeplinking_demo",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["D9:29:00:B9:30:F1:24:A0:E7:7A:58:74:43:C6:06:FF:F6:16:BB:42:F3:A2:16:10:5D:81:27:37:3A:E5:A6:14"]
  }
}]
```

4. Set up an android app with the applicationId : `com.pbc.deeplinking_demo`
5. Added the intent-filters with `autoVerify=true` to the activity

implementation below -

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="192.168.0.78" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>
```

With this config, I continue to see the disambiguation dialog asking me to choose between the default browser and the target app.

Note: I am able to access the mamp page & also the assetlinks.json  from Chrome on Android emulator.

Am I missing something here or is it not possible to test this in local environment?